# Is there an event that is triggered when an entry expires?

Tags: plugin-development, events, expiration, expired

I would like to update an entry after it has expired via a plugin. Is there an event that I can use to do this when using Craft 2?

Answer (score 1):

There is no event for this and it would not be possible via event since no one is executing any scripts. Unless there is a request there is no way for PHP to execute code on its own so you need to create a cronjob or a Craft task and execute your functions when someone visits the site.

I would create a cronjob that executes hourly and search for expired entries in order to find them. You can store a value in a field that is not in the layout of the model to mark it as "handled"